# How to Parallelize Array Creation?

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I have the following algo:

1. Iterate through all rows in 2d-array:
2. For each processed row I get 1d-array
3. Replace row *i* of other 2d-array with processed 1-d array

I'd like to parallelize the process as each row process is independant.

My code:

```
def update_grid_row(self, grid, new_neighbours_grid, y):
    grid_row = np.zeros(GRID_WIDTH + 2)
    for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH):
        xy_status = self.get_status_grid(x, y, grid, new_neighbours_grid)
        grid_row[x + 1] = xy_status

    return grid_row

def get_status_grid(self, x, y, new_grid, new_neighbours_grid):
    current_status = new_grid[x + 1][y + 1]
    living_neighbours = new_neighbours_grid[x][y]

    if living_neighbours < 2 or living_neighbours > 3:
        return int(0)
    elif current_status == 0 and living_neighbours == 3:
        return int(1)
    else:
        return current_status

def run  
    original_grid = self.grid
    new_grid = original_grid
    new_neighbours_grid = self.get_neighbours_grid(new_grid)
    for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
        grid_row = self.update_grid_row(original_grid, new_neighbours_grid, y)
        new_grid[:, y + 1] = grid_row.T
    self.grid = new_grid
```

Comment: There are a number of important details missing from your question. For starters: What is processing each row and producing the 1D arrays? What is the nature of the processing — is it compute bound? How big are these rows and arrays?

Comment: @martineau Thought it wasn't important, I edited my code and added the processing functions. The array is an integer 200x150, but it might increase to no more than 4000x4000 aprox.

Comment: You're probably not gonna get much performance out of multiprocessing, my recommendation would be to do all the processing in numpy

Comment: I agree with @Francisco — the overhead of using multiprocessing would very likely overwhelm any performance gained by making use of it for this problem.

Comment: As @FranciscoCouzo suggested, I changed the get status grid to process a whole row without for loops using numpy.where(condition, trueValue, falseValue). This speeded up the updating process 10x. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing is probably not useful, as pointed out in the comments, but notice that what your neighbor counting corresponds to convolving your grid with the array

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

So, using `scipy.signal.convolve2d` will buy you a factor of somewhere 10 and 100.